# iOS 7 - Twitter notification issue

Tags: ios, notifications, twitter

This has been getting me down, and I'm out of ideas.

On my main twitter account, for one person I follow (@IndieGala), every single tweet is sent as a notification.
After a quick bit of reading, I found two different methods to stop the tweets showing up, and I disabled it. A few hours later, they were showing up again.
So I repeatedly disabled them for a couple of weeks, and it didn't ever stick.

I then uninstalled and reinstalled the app, and that seemed to fix it. For about 15 hours, then once again the tweets started showing up.
If I go into settings and tweet notifications, the account is there. I disable it in that menu, and it vanishes. When the notification inevitably shows, it's back in the list as If I had never removed it.

I don't want to disable notifications entirely, and there is an account who's tweets I do want pushed so I don't want to disable that entirely either.

Has anyone had something similar to this? It's literally driving me to the edge of insanity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Twitter.com in to your account and change some stuff there.

**[Mute a single Account](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171399#)**

[image: mute]

If you click on "More" in the twitter timeline there is the "Mute", to stop seen someones tweets.

[image: mute in timeline]

If you want to be radical then Disable applications access for all:

[image: application access]